# YAML code to create a configmap with a particular file (.js/.sh)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

What will be the equivalent ConfigMap YAML code for the following command line?

```html
kubectl create configmap mongo-initdb --from-file=init-mongo.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a kubectl command that lets you get the generated yaml for a created config map. In your case:

```
kubectl get configmaps mongo-initdb -o yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command as suggested by Mo Xue, however here is YAML,

Example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongo-initdb
data:
  init-mongo.js: |
    <Content>
```

Read more about : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-directories

Answer (score 0):

```
Create the configmap from a file.
Just create a sample file like ui.properties
example:
cat ui.properties
1. name=x
2. rollno=y
    
Command to create a configmap from above file
kubectl create configmap ui-configmap --from-file=ui.properties

Verify the data.
kubectl get configmap ui-configmap  -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: <>
  name: ui-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  name: x
  role: y
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).